# Turing machine VS Push Down Automaton in CFL

Tags: turing-machines, context-free, pushdown-automata

I want to ask that between turing machine and pushdown automaton: which abstract machine can handle context-free language (CFL) in a more efficient way, and why?

I know that a pushdown automaton can use exactly one step per input symbol, which is a tight lower bound on efficiency. (If we’re measuring in number of steps, anyway.) This is better than a single-tape Turing machine can do. But, I think that a Turing machine with an input tape and a working tape can emulate a pushdown automaton directly, using the same number of steps.

So, in the end, which kind of automaton machine promisingly can serve as a **recognizer** for CFL?? And why?

Comment: You can simulate a DPDA with a Turing machine very efficiently, and a PDA with a nondeterministic Turing machine as efficiently.

Comment: So, you vote for turing machine?

Comment: It depends if you want it to be deterministic or not.

Comment: What about a general view?

Comment: The best known deterministic algorithm for accepting general context-free languages runs in matrix multiplication time, and there are time-space tradeoffs for the language of palindromes on single tape Turing machines.